# How to move my local WordPress site (on my PC - webmatrix) to live?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, webmatrix

I am new so please forgive me if I am not posting the question correctly.  I installed wordpress with webmatrix.  I created a new wordpress install and now I am ready to go live.  I have read a few posts but I am still lost.  I am using go daddy already have domain and web hosting economy plan - linux plan.  I have searched until I am blue in the face.  I have called go daddy, they cannot help me.  They want me to install a new wordpress site.  WHY.  I already have my site built,  it's on my local PC machine.  I need to get it from local to the web host.  I do not have my php admin. as everyone talks about.  I have web matrix, a PC.
I am looking for clear guidance/instructions.
1. Why do I have to install a new wordpress site from go daddy?
2.  If I do not, then,
    A.  Do I... login into my go daddy cpanel, create a new sql database? 
        i.  If so, this is where my confusion is.  steps are not clear on different sites.  Nothing is clear for webmatix, unless of course I missed it....  if so,                where do I the new sql database I created in go daddy cpanel, on my local pc hard drive?
    B.  Once I am clear on A.  Do I then go to my filezila ftp and move my wp local files - these would be the files from the local site I created, correct?  I               then put them in cpanel.
    C.  What next.  the database?  the database confuses me.  I do not have myphp admin., wamp, lamp, etc. How do I get my local database files from webmatrix – to go           daddy and once there, what do I do?   I have a PC I'm using web matrix (because the class I took said since I had a pc this is what I had to do to install              wordpress, they also said we had to use wpengine - so I have no idea how to deploy to another host - I cannot afford wpengines $29.00 month fee).          The database instructions are very confusing, export what and where, import what and where, rename - confused.  I cannot move my webhosting from go daddy, Paid for a year in advance and they will NOT refund my money, I already tried.  I cannot afford anything else at the moment.  So, I am stuck with them...
Can any one please help?  Thank you and I am sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options

1. (Best) Create a wordpress account in godaddy, import all your sites data and database to the new site. This is relatively easy to do and you can get Godaddy to walk you through it.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/move-your-wordpress-site-manually-12371

2. (Worst) On you home router, NAT ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) if you would like email you cannot get that working as all ISP's block outbound 25 traffic.

Setup a DDNS account as your home IP address is probably dynamic.

Add an A record for you site point to your DDNS IP

Comment: Hi Andrew.  1. will not work.  They want me to install a fresh new install for wordpress.  Why?  As I mentioned above.  2.  I have not idea what you're talking about NAT, ISP traffice, etc. Thank you though.